# Show an android soft-keyboard in the graphical layout of eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, android-softkeyboard

I googled this but there wasnt even a topic about it. So Im asking here. Is it possible to show the keyboard type which i use for an activity in the graphical layout editor in eclipse?

Im using an activity where the keyboard is always up and cant disappear by user input. That  feature would be nice to set up a layout for this. To set views on the upper edge of the keyboard and stuff.

Comment: The keyboard is a configurable thing on android, so I guess if you want to control it you will have to implement your own keyboard.Which is not a good practice anyway since the user used to its keyboard